Blazor .net 8 new interactive project structure fails to connect to debug adapter
I recently started to play around with new Blazor project structure to see if we can move our front-end projects to .net 8. The problem is, I'm not able to connect to chromium debug adapter.
I want to run my server app which serves a razor page with SSR. The client wasm app then loads and takes over the front-end using builder.RootComponents.Add<ClientApp>("#app");.
In .net 7, visual studio seemed to detect the browser connection and add it to the process list after an item named "N/A", but now I have:

Here is a reproduceable sample repo, I'd be thankful if you could get it to work: DebugAdapterTest
Some additional info:

I'm using latest .net 8 SDK (8.0.303) and VS2022 (17.10.4)
We prefer the project structure to remain the same.
I can run the project with no "Failed to launch debug adapter" error on FireFox and Brave, but the adapter still doesn't work. My main choice of browser for development is MS Edge.
Already deleted .vs folder, played with debugging settings, and basically everything suggested in this thread and more. Please provide instructions on how you'd get the sample repo to work.

Let me know if I can give more information.

Hi Bamdad, may I know what is happening when remove inspectUri in your launchsetting.json files?

And how about create a brand new sample like the link? Maybe we can check if it works or not.

@JasonPan Totally. If I remove inspectUri, the app runs with no problems, but obviously  debugging wasm is not possible (Which is the point of the issue). I just made the sample project from scratch, so I don't know if there is anything to be done in the process of creation that can affect the outcome.
